# Track Eclipse plugin class invocation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse plugin ( Also the code is available ) that automatically arrange graphical components by clicking "Arrange" button.
How can I see the underlying class invocation of the arranging process done by this plugin.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please be more specific.  Are you looking to log all constructor invocations?

Comment: This would help, yes please

Comment: Yes, what?  What exactly are you trying to do? Be specific and give an example.

Comment: I want to log all class constructions and invocations.